# Is the moderator election feature available on Stack Overflow Enterprise version?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-enterprise

How are moderators chosen on Stack Overflow Enterprise?  Can we run elections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an enterprise setting, moderators would be more considered *administrators*, and appointed by the organization rather than being democratically-elected by the employees using the instance. That doesn't mean that an organization couldn't ask people to draw straws, or even nominate coworkers to fill the administrative roles, but elections as you've come to know them aren't built into the enterprise edition.

Typically, a *department* should have administrative duties (such as your internal IT department) so that they become a function of a group. This helps ensure that as folks come and go from your organization, their access is adjusted in accordance with whatever your policies might be.

A significant amount of our election work is actually manual, so I don't know what kind of interest we'd need to see in order to port it over to private instances; I suspect it would need to be considerable.

But, that doesn't inhibit you from *having* an election (say the regents of a university research department are all contenders to become administrators of a given system, but 3 who want the responsibility need to be chosen), it just means you'd have to manually hand out access after holding a STV election on another platform, but even with *our* system, that's still manual.

Feel free to let me know if I've misunderstood your question. Moderation on private instances consists more of *organizational* policies and less of just consensus among active participants, but you don't *have* to use that model, it's just the most common approach (and why many of the public moderation tools just don't make much sense to port over).